# Unordered result because of an ambiguous grammar using Flex and Bison

Tags: compilation, grammar, bison, flex-lexer, ambiguous-grammar

I'm trying to create a section for variable declaration (a bit similar to HTML) using Flex and Bison, my grammar is correct (no lexical or syntax errors), but the displayed result isn't ordered.

**example.txt:**

```
    <SUB VARIABLE>
        < a AS INT />;
        <string AS STR />; 
        < x | y AS FLT />;
        <bool AS BOL />; 
        <char AS CHR />; 
    </SUB VARIABLE>
```

**the result I get (the incorrect one):**

```
a ---> 1
x ---> 2
y ---> 2
string ---> 4
char ---> 3
bool ---> 5
```

**the result I want to display (the correct one):**

```
a ---> 1
string ---> 4
x ---> 2
y ---> 2
bool ---> 5
char ---> 3
```

Here's my code:

**synt.y:**

```
DECLARATION:    DECLARATION     '<' SUB VARIABLE '>'    SUITE  
            
            |
;


SUITE: '<' idf  SUITE_VAR {inserer($2,getType());}
            | '<' '/' SUB VARIABLE '>' 
;

SUITE_VAR:      '|' idf  SUITE_VAR {inserer($2, getType());}
            |   AS INT '/' '>' ';' SUITE {setType(1);}
            |   AS FLT '/' '>' ';' SUITE {setType(2);}
            |   AS CHR '/' '>' ';' SUITE {setType(3);}
            |   AS STR '/' '>' ';' SUITE {setType(4);}
            |   AS BOL '/' '>' ';' SUITE {setType(5);}
;
```

My grammar may be ambiguous, I tried many other grammars but I had the same problem.
Could you please tell me how I should write my grammar to have an ordered result?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your grammar were ambiguous, bison would report parsing conflicts. An ambiguous grammar cannot produce a parser without conflicts.

Comment: That's true. Even if the result is incorrect, I didn't have warnings nor conflicts. I want to list the variables in order, could you please help me know my mistake in this grammar ?

Comment: Think about how your semantic actions work. Remember that an action is executed (logically) at the end of the input matched, which means that the actions for all contained non-terminals have already been executed. The result is that left-recursive rules evaluate left-to-right, while right-recursive rules evaluate right-to-left. Right-recursive grammars are almost never correct, particularly if rules have side effects. (But you should prefer rules without side-effects, which return a semantic value by setting `$$`.)

Comment: Anyway, your grammar is a mess, perhaps because you were trying to force it to satisfy top-down restrictions. Bison generates bottom-up grammars; you can freely use left-recursion and there's no need for left-factoring. So you can write grammars in a more natural style.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a mistake in your grammar. It's the semantics of the `inserer` function where you probably have an issue.